# Fraction line in French

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques

What is a better translation of a *"fraction line"* into French?

I have two:

> - ligne de fraction
> - barre de fraction

"fraction line" is a line between the nominator and denominator of a fraction. It looks like a horizontal line or a slash.

I think that the 2nd one is better.

[image]

EDIT: maybe there is a difference between the line that appears in the horizontal vs diagonal fraction.

Comment: In what context are you saying fraction line? Because in English, one normally just talks about the numerator and the denominator. Can you give us more context??

Comment: @Lambie In English when you write a fraction vertical fraction you have 3 elements: a numerator, a **fraction bar** and a denominator, see [an example](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/fraction-bar.html) on a site for kids.  When you write a linear fraction you also have 3 elements: a numerator, a **stroke** (they call it slash in the US) and a denominator, see the [fraction article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)) on Wikipedia. Although OP's English is not really good, the picture they're pointing to makes the question and context very clear.

Comment: It's still not clear. Fraction bar? Stroke? Slash in the US?  A stroke or slash in the US is always on an angle. So, it's not what the dividing line between the numerator and denominator is called. It's just a (horizontal or diagonal, in some typography) line separating the two. Now, in what context would one need to name that? A fair question,  isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

In French, like in English, you can write a fraction horizontally or vertically. You use a *barre de fraction* ("fraction bar" in English) to separate the numerator from the denominator. When the fraction is written horizontally the *barre de fraction* is called a *barre oblique* ("fraction slash" or "fraction stroke" in English).

Comment: I would also add *barre de division*. Note that your last sentence might be (mis)understood to mean an horizontal bar is a *barre oblique*, which is defying geometry ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed. In case it could really be misunderstood I've repeated the word fraction. I did not mention *barre de division* because here I am not describing a mathematical operation but just naming an object. OP didn't ask for "division bar" but for "fraction (line)bar" .

Answer (score 4):

> Le trait ou barre de fraction ou vinculum signifie que l'on divise le numérateur par le dénominateur.

-- [Wikipedia: Fraction (mathématiques)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(math%C3%A9matiques))

Answer (score 1):

I've studied math and physics for a bunch of years, I've heard "*barre de fraction*" much, much more.